# Is it possible to pass some content to a {{partial}}?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Say I had a template that was like:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="something">
    <div class="thisIsJustAnExample">Something I wanted in the template</div>
        {{outlet}}
    <div class="thisIsJustAnotherExample">Something else I wanted in the template</div>
</script>
```

And do the following in another template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="thisThingPutsSomethingInSomething">
    <span>
        {{#partial "something"}}
            <div>Some stuff I want to go into the outlet...</div>
        {{/partial}}
    </span>
</script>
```

So the result is:

```
<div class="thisIsJustAnExample">Something I wanted in the template</div>
    <div>Some stuff I want to go into the outlet...</div>
<div class="thisIsJustAnotherExample">Something else I wanted in the template</div>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a view this can be easily accomplished:

Parent Template and View

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="foo">
  hello {{yield}} world
</script>


App.FooView = Em.View.extend({
  layoutName:'foo'
});
```

Usage

```
{{#view App.FooView}}
  {{item}}
{{/view}}
```

Example

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/deluxaha/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

Just load the {{partial}} at the place of your {{outlet}}. You can achieve the final output.

Jsbin - [Link](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/menuv/1/edit)

**Note**: Your partial template-name should begin with a "_" refer the link - [Partial_naming_convention](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/rendering-with-helpers/#toc_the-code-partial-code-helper)